# Azure App Gateway v2 - Nginx headers or cookies too large

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-application-gateway

Azure Application Gateway v2 use nginx and is limited to a header/cookie size of 8kb.

I'm using an oauth provider that send claims, such as the user profile, making the headers above 8kb. Is there a way to augment said limit to let's say 16kb? I have identified this problem by limiting the number of claims returned.

Otherwise when I receive my response from the auth provider I get a 502 from the application gateway.

Comment: It seems to be a known problem on uservoice without any microsoft answer. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/36087544-support-for-header-content-size-configuration

Comment: is this still a problem ?